# django query db on every request

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i have a navigation element that is determined by values in a database.

no matter what view it is, i need to get these navigation objects out of the database.

where in the code can i tell it to set a template variable containing all the navigation objeccts without setting it in every view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a good use for a [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

Comment: thanks, this was what I was looking for, and in general solved a lot of questions I had about django.

Answer (score 1):

Right way to do this is to use templatetag. Then you don't have to include it in every view, just in your templates like {% load navigation %} {% navigation %}

How to write one:

- [django docs on template tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) (read overview and [inclusion tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags))
- [anoher resource](http://codespatter.com/2009/01/22/how-to-write-django-template-tags/)